# Why react-devtools is showing many instances of the application?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Today I started the using of react-devtools and I saw 3 instances of the same application.

Is that right? What should I be doing wrong?

As we can see in the image below, there are 3 instances of Provider for the same application.
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146388/editable-form-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check the source in the browser maybe your script is included many times.