# Editable Form ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
let _ = require('lodash');

import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {fetchedBeaconsEdit} from '../../actions/';
import {editBeacon} from '../../actions/index';

// TODO - come up with a decent name

class InfoRow extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <tr>
                <td>
              { this.props.beacon === "name" 
                || this.props.beacon === "major" 
                || this.props.beacon === "minor" 
                || this.props.beacon === "beaconType" ?
                  <span>{this.props.beacon}<span className="font-css top">*</span></span>:
                  <span>{this.props.beacon}</span>
              }

                </td>
                <td>

                { this.props.beacon !== "beaconType" && 
                  this.props.beacon !== "uuid" && 
                  this.props.beacon !== "status" && 
                  this.props.beacon !== "store"&&
                  this.props.beacon !== "group" ?
                <div>
                    <input type="text"
                       className="form-control"
                       defaultValue={this.props.beaconValue}
                       name={this.props.beaconValue}
                       onChange={(e) =>this.props.handleInputChangeProp(e.target.value)}
                    /></div>:

                    this.props.beacon === "uuid" && this.props.beacon === "status" && this.props.beacon=== "store"?
                  <span></span>:

                    this.props.beacon === "beaconType"?

                    <select defaultValue={this.props.beaconValue} name={this.props.beaconValue} className="form-control" onChange={(e) =>this.props.handleInputChangeProp(e.target.value)}>
                      
                      <option name="ibeacon">IBEACON</option>
                      <option name="eddystone">EDDYSTONE</option>
                    </select>:this.props.beaconValue

                    

                }



                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

class BeaconEdit extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            
        };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(beacon, value) {

        this.setState({
            [beacon]: value
        });
    }

 handleClick = () =>{
       Object.keys(this.props.ebcn).map((key)=> {
        if (this.state[key] !== undefined) {
          this.props.editBeaconGroup[key]=this.state[key];
        }
            
       })
        this.props.handleSubmitProp(this.props.editBeaconGroup);
  }
 
    render() {

        const rows = [];
        let a = this.props.ebcn;

        

       Object.keys(this.props.ebcn).map((keyName, keyIndex) =>{

          if (keyName === "store" || keyName === "group") {
            return rows.push(<InfoRow beacon={keyName} beaconValue={a[keyName].name.toString()} name={this.state[keyName]} key={keyIndex} handleInputChangeProp={(inp) =>this.handleInputChange(keyName, inp)}/>);
          }else{
            return rows.push(<InfoRow beacon={keyName} beaconValue={a[keyName].toString()} name={this.state[keyName]} key={keyIndex} handleInputChangeProp={(inp) =>this.handleInputChange(keyName, inp)}/>);
       }
       });

        return (


            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="">

                  <table className="table table-clear">
                    <tbody>
              
                    {rows}
                    
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                 </div>
                 <div className="px-1" >
                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-size btn-block" onClick={this.handleClick}>Save</button>
                 </div>
          </div>

        )

    }


}

class BeaconDetailEditComponent extends Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        editbeacons: {}
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

        this.validateName = this.validateName.bind(this);
        this.validateMajor = this.validateMajor.bind(this);
        this.validateMinor = this.validateMinor.bind(this);
    }

    validateMinor = (minor) => {
      var re = /^[0-9]+$/;
      return re.test(minor);
    }

    validateMajor = (major) => {
      var re = /^[0-9]+$/;
      return re.test(major);
    }

    validateName = (name) => { 
      var re = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
      return re.test(name); 
    };


  handleSubmit (beaconedited) {

    console.log(beaconedited.name);

    if (!this.validateName(beaconedited.name)) { 
              alert('Name can not be an integer')  
          }

    else if (!this.validateMajor(beaconedited.major)) { 
              alert('Major number can only be an integer')  
          }

        else if (beaconedited.major.length > 5) {
          alert('Major number can not exceed 5 digits')
        }

        else if (!this.validateMinor(beaconedited.minor)) { 
              alert('Minor number can only be an integer')  
          }

        else if (beaconedited.major > 65535) {
          alert('Major number can not exceed the limit of 65535')
        }

        else if (beaconedited.minor > 65535) {
          alert('Minor number can not exceed the limit of 65535')
        }

    else {

      this.props.editBeacon(beaconedited, this.props.location.query.id);
    
  }
    }

  componentWillMount = () => {
        this.props.fetchedBeaconsEdit(this.props.location.query.id);  
    };

  
  render() {
    
    return (
        <div className="container px-3 mr-3">
            <div>
              <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><h1>Edit Beacon Information</h1></div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
                { this.props.ebcn != null?
            <div>
                <BeaconEdit ebcn={this.props.ebcn} handleSubmitProp={this.handleSubmit} editBeaconGroup={this.state.editbeacons}/>
            </div> :
                    <center><img className="gif-size" src={'img/avatars/default.gif'} alt="Loading"/></center>

            }
        </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        eBeacon: state.eBeacon,
        ebcn: state.beacons
    }

}


function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({editBeacon: editBeacon, fetchedBeaconsEdit: fetchedBeaconsEdit}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(BeaconDetailEditComponent);
```

[image: This is the output I'm getting right now]

[image]

i had provided the code snippet
what i am doing is 
i had fetched the values from the server and were shown in the fields and I'm making this page as editable form
what i want to do is now to take the values changed or changed by the user and to print them in console.
i had applied handleInputChange and its showing changed values while changing but i want to see those values in console on button click as well
how to do it?

Comment: on which ButtonClick do you want to see those values and also if it for all the values or only specific ones

Comment: wanted all the form values on clicking save button as you can see in the image

Comment: One small question more, you are not passing any prop as name to the InfoRow component, how is it working?? Shouldn't it be `this.props.beacon`

Comment: i had uploaded one more pic
you can see that as well
Hope u got my point

Comment: Any solution you got brother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the manner your are changing the state is not good. You are setting the new state to have only a single attribute which is the name and value of the field which is modified.

Coming to how to print the value of the field you are modifying, you should do a console log in the handle change method.

That said, your code should look like:

```
handleInputChange(event) {

    //const {name, value} = event.target;
    //const oldState = this.state;
    //const newState = Object.assign({},oldState,{[name]:value});
    //this.setState(newState);

    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });

    //printing the input name and value as it is being modified.
    console.log(name + ":" + value);

    //if you want to see the value of the current state uncomment the line below
    //console.log("State=" + JSON.stringify(newState));

}

printState = () => {
  console.log("State="+JSON.stringify(this.state));
}
```

For more insight on how to modify objects with assign method see: [MDN doc on Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

If you want to print the current state on clicking the save button then add the onClick attribute to the button as shown in the code below:

```
<button value="Save" onClick={this.printState}/>
```

Comment: i got it but i want to print to console on clicking on save button
and also i want to print every  value on Click whether it was changed or not

Comment: I just added some more stuff to my answer.

Comment: button already added as you can see inn code but it doesn't helped what u suggested

Comment: @cdaiga  _the manner your are changing the state is not good. You are setting the new state to have only a single attribute_ - I don't agree. `setState` performs shallow merge of next state object into current state so new state will not have only single property. Please check React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: can you provide solution?

Comment: @Piyush add `onClick={() => {console.log("State=" + JSON.stringify(this.state));}}` to your save button. See the last line of my answer.

Comment: Add the code of the button on your question or below as comment.

Comment: I just modified the code of the button on the last line of my answer, and also added another method `printState` to your Component Class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153407/show-mobile-component-reactjs

Comment: You confirmed in your comment above that it printed null. You wanted to print the state. You should be looking at why it's that;

Comment: @Piyush that's not how stackoverflow is to be used

Answer (score 1):

Change InfoRow to

```
class InfoRow extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <tr>
                <td>
                  {this.props.beacon}
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text"
                   className="form-control"
                   defaultValue={this.props.beaconValue}
                   value={this.props.name}
                   name={this.props.beaconValue}
                   onChange={(e) =>this.props.handleInputChangeProp(e.target.value)}
                />
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

and render to

```
Object.keys(this.props.ebcn).map((keyName, keyIndex) =>{

          return rows.push(<InfoRow beacon={keyName} beaconValue={a[keyName].toString()} name={this.state[keyName]} key={keyIndex} handleInputChangeProp={(inp) =>this.handleInputChange(keyName, inp)}/>);
       });
```

and

```
handleInputChange(beacon, value) {

        this.setState({
            [beacon]: value
        });
    }
```

and handleClick to

```
 handleClick = () =>{
       Object.keys(this.props.ebcn).map((key)=> {
            console.log(this.state[key]);
       }))
  }
```

Comment: Try this solution, and let me know if it works, Of course its not tested and may have a few bugs

Comment: syntax error was removed but having error in this line as

'beacon' is not defined

return rows.push(<InfoRow beacon={keyName} beaconValue={a[keyName].toString()} name={this.state[beacon]} key={keyIndex} handleInputChangeProp={(inp) =>this.handleInputChange(keyName, inp)}/>);
       });

Comment: Warning: InfoRow is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

Comment: on button click 
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
in this
console.log(this.state[key]);

Comment: The second error occurs because of context binding, andthe first one because initially this.state[keyName] is undefined

Comment: any solution for that?

even after changing anything in fields shows [object] [object]

Comment: value I'm changing only those were showing in console on clicking the button
rest were shown undefined

Cant you do like to store all values in array and console it afterwards

Comment: i fixed the problem bro... got a lot of help from your answer

Comment: Glad it helped Piyush :)

Comment: one thing i wanted to ask ?
 as we passed like this return rows.push(<InfoRow beacon={keyName} beaconValue={a[keyName].toString()}    and in InfoRow i want to access the name of column name being fetched 
Like now we passed beacon so it contains all the column names what if i have to access only one like named as "name"

Comment: @Piyush, I did not understand what you want

Comment: i had updated the code but the thing is i was not able to print the default values of input fields in the console How to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694280/how-to-show-a-getting-started-popup-in-react-js